# el compilador me da error usando la librería winsock

Tags: c

```
prueba.cpp:(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'
```

No entiendo a que se debe , asi con todas las variables relacionadas con winsock usadas en el programa y, en este caso me sigue tirando error a pesar de que no lo encuentro explicación alguna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El enlazador te está diciendo que no encuentra el código binario correspondiente a esa función y, en consecuencia, no sabe a qué código debe llamarse cuando se invoca esa función.

Todo apunta a que no estás enlazando con las librerías de winsock, que son:

- Librería antigua: `ws_32.lib`
- Librería winsock2 actual: `ws2_32.lib`

Los pasos a seguir para indicar al compilador que debe enlazar con esa librería dependen de si estás usando Visual Studio, cmake, makefiles a pelo, CodeBlocks, el infame DevCpp, etc.